# Creating AWS Managed version of imported SSL certificate in AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-acm

There is a purchased SSL certificate of one of my domains and it's imported to AWS Certificate Manager. It's working without a problem. But I realized that my SSL certificate is expiring and I don't want to purchase a new one. So I decided to create AWS Managed version of my certificate. I created new AWS managed cert for the same domain set like my imported cert. I validated it via Route 53, everything seems nice except `Renewal Eligibility`. My new AWS managed certificate acts like imported in this matter I guess, Shows `Ineligible` and **also expiration dates are exactly the same with imported one**. I'm wondering why this is happening. Is it impossible to migrate from imported to AWS Managed for SSL certificates? Since this seems a little suspicious to me, I didn't integrate AWS Managed Certificate to any of my load balancers.

Any help or recommendation would be highly apprecited,
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, yes it showed `Ineligible` because I didn't attach certificate to any of my load balancers, when I attach it for testing purposes, it immediately started to work and Renewal Eligibility turned into `Eligible`. When I detach certificate from my load balancers, it turned into `Ineligible` again.